# What's the meaning of 'to' here?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

It is a partnership agreement where one partner can bind all partners in an agreement **to** partnership debts.

I thinks it means, with respect to, but still i have doubt...

Comment: The sentence does not make literal sense: “agreement to debts” is meaningless. A word may be missing such as “incur”. Or it may be an incorrect word, such as “to” being incorrectly substituted for “on.” We need more of the context to help.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.biz2credit.com/business-toolkit/business-glossary/mutual-agency&ved=2ahUKEwi6r_SYgeX6AhU4TmwGHRjmDAsQFnoECCsQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3uoeF3fPYaW4p6mEYSEyIb  —this is the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definition from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to) seems to apply the best:

**7 a** —used as a function word (1) to indicate the application of an adjective or a noun
*// agreeable to everyone

// attitude to friends

// title to the property*

In the example of "title to property" in particular, "to" seems to have the same function as in "agreement to debts". So "to" indicates where something applies. In your case, it means the agreement applies to debts.

Answer (score 0):

The citation quoted is not good English. What is meant is

> mutual agency is the legal power of each partner to bind the partnership (and derivatively each and every partner individually) to a contract, inluding contracts to incur debt.

Comment: Bind the partnership **to** a contract mean?

Comment: It means to do those things legally necessary to make the terms of a contract enforceable against the partnership by a court of competent jurisdiction.

Comment: @JeffMorrow just the word "to" is the question, not the entire sentence

Comment: @gotube The problem is that “to” is not idiomatic in that sentence. No one says “agreement to debts.”

Comment: @JeffMorrow I agree that "agreement to debts" is unnatural, but I didn't parse it that way. Read it again, but leave out "in an agreement" and treat it as a redundant phrase. It's still bad writing, but it's a way to parse it that makes sense. With that reading, "to debts" modifies "bind all partners", which is quite logical.

Comment: @gotube Please look at my initial comment, where I pointed out that it was easy enough to correct the sentence to make it idiomatic and to make it approximately correct. You cannot, however, make the statement convey the correct idea by replacing “to” with “to incur” or any other simple fix. Perhaps, I should reference my initial comment in my answer?